# nohup is not working as I am exiting the terminal

Tags: centos, nohup

I was trying to use `nohup` like that:

```
 nohup python fibo.py & > a.out
```

When I do so and try to exit from the shell it prompts that "you have running jobs". But that should not be the case.

```
$ nohup python test.py & > a.txt    
[1]     21608    
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

$ jobs -l    
[1] + 21608      Running                 nohup python test.py & > a.txt    

$ exit    
You have running jobs
```

Comment: _How_ were you trying to use `nohup` exactly?  What was the invocation?  What is the output of the `jobs` command?

Comment: If you are just launching the command with `nohup your_command` and than use ctrl+z to send it to background it may say that it is already running. You can use `bg` after that to properly send it to background or better use correct nohup syntax in the first place: `nohup your_command &`

Comment: I used the command nohup python fibo.py & > a.out

Answer (score 7):

When you run

```
$ nohup some-command &
```

there *is* a job running in the background until `some-command` exits.  `nohup` only disconnects the command from the terminal; `disown` removes it from the jobs list.  It seems to me your intended syntax is

```
$ nohup python test.py > a.out & disown
```

---

Note that the syntax used in the question has `> a.out` *after* the `&` that ends the command.  This means that the output of `test.py` is *not* being sent to `a.out` — instead, it is being appended to `nohup.out` as the message indicates.