# Keep reverse SSH tunnel opened via java application when the app is stopped

Tags: ssh, process, java

As discussed in the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66850870/java-persistent-reverse-ssh-process/66851123#66851123) I am creating a Java program that starts a reverse SSH tunnel. I have created a script `/root/reverse.sh` that starts a subshell and creates a detached ssh reverse session:

```
#!/bin/bash
( /usr/bin/sshpass -p mypassword ssh -f -N -M -S /tmp/socketuser000.000.000.000 -p 0000 user@000.000.000.000 -R 21022:localhost:22 -R 21080:localhost:80 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no )
```

Then this script is executed from java as:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash /root/reverse.sh");
int result = process.waitFor();
```

The connection works just fine, the problem comes when I stop the java program, which is registered as a system service:

```
systemctl stop myapp
```

When the java process is killed the reverse ssh connection is killed too. I have checked via `pstree` that the reverse ssh process parent is PID 1 and not Java.

```
$ pstree -sg 2185
systemd(1)───ssh(2185)
```

I don't understand why when I kill the Java process the ssh process is killed too as it's not a child of the Java process. Why does this happen? Has this something to do with process groups? How can I prevent the ssh process from being killed?

Answer (score 1):

Your process is getting `SIG_HUP` or `SIG_INT` when parent (java) process is exiting.

You may try running it with `nohup` so it will ignore SIG_HUP signal.
Also you may include:

```
trap 'echo "Got sigint"' INT
```

in your `.sh` file, so instead of exiting normal way it would handle SIG_INT by echoing text. Feel free to use any other function to handle signals.

Also there is very good answer about signals here: [What causes various signals to be sent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/what-causes-various-signals-to-be-sent)

Please consider changing your approach to this problem as this looks like a bad design pattern when you expect service to do something and keep doing it when service is stopped.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I have tried changing the script execution command to `nohup /bin/bash /root/reverse.sh` and I have also changed the ssh command inside the script to `nohup /usr/bin/sshpass -p mypassword ssh -f -N -M -S /tmp/socketuser000.000.000.000 -p 0000 user@000.000.000.000 -R 21022:localhost:22 -R 21080:localhost:80 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. Unfortunately I am getting the same behaviour where the SSH connection is closed when the service is stopped.

Comment: I have also tried adding `& disown` at the end of the commands as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421539/nohup-is-not-working-as-i-am-exiting-the-terminal which also didn't work.

Comment: @PauMAVA: Updated my answer according to your description.